# Labeling different plots

Tags: plotting, labeling

I have data stored in a nested list and I have to plot them. I have something like this

```
Table[DiscretePlot[Data[[m, n]], {n, 1, 2100}],{m, 3, 48, 6}]
```

Data is just a list of many sublists and I have to plot just some of them. For every plot I have to add a label like $t=100$ but the labels have to be different for each plot. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: It would be helpful to know more precisely how your "Data" is structured. Can you provide an abbreviated sample, say, a couple of lines?

Comment: It is a really huge amount of data. The structure is the following
Data={{},........,{}}
There are 48 sublists, and each list is made out of many numbers (4000 elements)

Answer (score 1):

```
Data = RandomReal[1, {3, 10}];

labels = {100, 200, 300};

Table[DiscretePlot[Data[[m, n]], {n, 1, 8}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Label: t=" <> ToString @ labels[[m]]], {m, 1, 3}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
data = RandomReal[1, {48, 2100}];
labels = Table[Row[{"Label: t=", 100 t}], {t, 3, 48, 6}]; 

Labeled[DiscretePlot[#[[n]], {n, 1, 2100}], #2, Top] & @@@
  Transpose[{data[[Range[3, 48, 6]]], labels}]
```

or

```
DiscretePlot[#[[n]], {n, 1, 2100}, PlotLabel -> #2] & @@@ 
 Transpose[{data[[Range[3, 48, 6]]], labels}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]